# Selenium can't aviod detection with webdrive

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I have tested every method but still can't pass the block some reason. Not even trying to automate anything. Example page [URL](https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/yedek-parca-aksesuar-donanim-tuning-otomotiv-ekipmanlari-yedek-parca-linea-euro-5-enjektoru-0445110351-55219886-515913059/detay). I can access main page but can't access any link inside the web site with webdriver. 
Java Code:

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--disable-blink-features");
    options.addArguments("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled");
    options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
    options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/hayvanlar-alemi-aksesuarlar-buyukbas-kucukbas-10x60-hayvan-yasam-alani-600metrekare-706539205/detay");
```

Comment: Did you try to change User Agent?

Comment: Yes, I've tried but still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked with firefox driver + useragent + enabling javascript. I think I had some version issues on google driver.